# Reading file from unknown path

Tags: java, file, stream

The following code reads a text file from a specific path.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Game {
static FileInputStream fin = null;
static DataInputStream din = null;
static BufferedReader br = null;

public void run()
{
    fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\USER 1\\Desktop\\Project Java\\players.txt");
    din = new DataInputStream(fin);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
...}
```

My problem is that i want to read the players.txt file from any path, for example if i run the program from another machine where the path will not be the same.

Comment: "i want to read the players.txt file from any path" <- Thats not going to work exactly. In the end your programm needs to know an exact path where to find the players.txt. You can of course let the user enter the path where the file is or use a relative path and have the requirement that the players.txt is always in the relative path to the path where the program gets excecuted (e.G. players.txt must be in the same directory that you run the program from)

Comment: You can have relative paths. Try to just specify "players.txt" - it will be expected to reside in the same dir as you started the application from.

Comment: To be precise: that call reads a text file from a specific **string**; which happens to be an absolute file path. So, before you dive into the depths of file IO operations with Java, may I suggest that you learn about some of the basics, like "how to put together a string" ... from two other strings? Because then you can fully control in which path you want to search for. It could be "relative" ... or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `config.properties` file in your class path and store the path to the file in a variable like this

```
pathToFile = C:\Users\USER 1\Desktop\Project Java\
nameOfFile = players.txt
```

Then, create a `Config` class and read the *properties* file using the `Properties` class [supplied by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Create the appropriate setters and getters of the aforementioned two variables inside the `Config` class and read the file like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import packagename.Config;
public class Game {
    static FileInputStream fin = null;
    static DataInputStream din = null;
    static BufferedReader br = null;
    static Config config = new Config();

    public void run() {
        fin = new FileInputStream(config.getPathToFile + config.getFileName);
        din = new DataInputStream(fin);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
}
```

With this method, you'll have stored the path to the file **externally**, so every time you want to run your Java program to another machine, you'd just have to edit the `config.properties` file and execute the `jar` from the console, with **no** code modifications.

**NOTE**

As a "best" practice, avoid including hardcoded paths or names that are anytime subject to change (folder names, DB fields etc.). As a first rule, always "gather" these names in a central location, in our case a class. By doing so, every time a name changes, you just have to change it *once* instead of searching it across your entire project.

As a second rule, isolate these names from your code, to allow it to be executed without any code change inside a properties file, regardless of folder structure, OS used etc. By doing so, even someone who does not know Java or programming at all, can rename a couple of variables in a text file and run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of absolute

```
fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\USER 1\\Desktop\\Project Java\\players.txt");
```

use relative paths, for example:

```
fin = new FileInputStream("../input/players.txt");
```

Comment: Relative paths only allow to omit the path that the project is located but work only for files that are stored *in* the classpath. If he want's to load the file from wherever it is stored in the OS, regardless of the OS itslef, he has to create a properties file.